# Zooming in on ubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

How can I zoom in using a touchpad in google chrome in Ubuntu?
In windows, we can do so directly. But in ubuntu, I am not able to do this.
Please suggest some setting changes.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Does the touchpad work in other apps other then Chrome? How have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

This works in Ubuntu 20.04.3 and I suspect in most versions:

Hold down ctrl and slide 2 fingers down the touchpad to zoom in and ctrl-slide up to zoom out. (You might have to enable 2 finger scrolling in mouse and touchpad settings although it’s usually enabled by default.)

If you are using a mouse with a wheel, hold down ctrl and the wheel does the same thing.